# What is the Python equivalence of Perl's DOTMULTI and DOTDOTMULTI

Tags: python, regex, string, perl

I'm trying to understand [this perl code](https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/tokenizer/tokenizer.perl).

And in the code it uses regexes containing `DOTMULTI` and `DOTDOTMULTI` like:

```
#multi-dots stay together
$text =~ s/\.([\.]+)/ DOTMULTI$1/g;
while($text =~ /DOTMULTI\./)
{
    $text =~ s/DOTMULTI\.([^\.])/DOTDOTMULTI $1/g;
    $text =~ s/DOTMULTI\./DOTDOTMULTI/g;
}
```

I have tried looking through the Perl docs for `DOTMULTI` but I couldn't find any hint of it. From the code, https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/tokenizer/tokenizer.perl , only the while loop in line 270 and 258 uses `DOTMULTI`.

**Is there a Python equivalence of `DOTMULTI` and `DOTDOTMULTI`?**

Given that we know the `DOTMULTI` and `DOTDOTMULTI` equivalence from Perl in Python, would this in Python:

```
re.sub(r'{}\.([^\.])'.format(DOTMULTI), r'{} \1'.format(DOTDOTMULTI), text)
```

be the equivalence of this in Perl:

```
$text =~ s/DOTMULTI\.([^\.])/DOTDOTMULTI $1/g;
```

Comment: `DOTMULTI` is just a string literal. In your Python code, `DOTMULTI` is a variable instead. So, no, it is not the equivalent.

Comment: I mean given that I know what `DOTMULTI` is in perl.

Comment: Could you just explain what input you have and what output you expect?

Comment: @alvas: are you getting that confused with the [`m` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers)? I can't find any references to `DOTMULTI` being a feature. It certainly is a string literal in the code you link to.

Comment: @alvas: otherwise, please link to something explaining what `DOTMULTI` is in perl so I can understand it and translate it for you to Python.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I'm not sure what `DOTMULTI` is in Perl though, so I'm not exactly sure what the output should be. But is `DOTMULTI` som sort of built in variable in Perl?

Comment: In `s/\.([\.]+)/ DOTMULTI$1/g;`, `DOTMULTI` is a *string*, a part of a replacement pattern. This code finds `\.([\.]+)` pattern and replaces it with " DOTMULTI" + the capture group 1 text, multiple times (due to `/g`)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I'm also unsure where was `DOTMULTI` initialized in https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/tokenizer/tokenizer.perl I can't find it from the Perl docs too, hence the question.

Comment: It is not initialized anywhere in the perl code you linked https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/tokenizer/tokenizer.perl#L358. In there the string `DOTMULTI` is a literal string to be matched. If it was a variable reference in perl, it would have a `$` sigil on it.

Comment: @msw Ahhh... now I think i'm getting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magic `DOTMULTI` functionality involved here. The code inserts a *string literal*, to then anchor further replacements on that string literal.

The Python equivalent would be:

```
text = re.sub(r'\.([\.]+)', r' DOTMULTI\1', text)

while re.search(r'DOTMULTI\.', text):
    text = re.sub(r'DOTMULTI\.([^\.])', r'DOTDOTMULTI \1', text)
    text = re.sub(r'DOTMULTI\.', 'DOTDOTMULTI', text)
```

So `'Some text...'` becomes `'Some text DOTMULTI..'`, which then becomes `'Some text DOTDOTMULTI.'`, which then becomes `'Some text DOTDOTDOTMULTI'`.

This text is [further onwards in the same code](https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/tokenizer/tokenizer.perl#L357-L362) replaced with dots again:

```perl
#restore multi-dots
while($text =~ /DOTDOTMULTI/)
{
    $text =~ s/DOTDOTMULTI/DOTMULTI./g;
}
$text =~ s/DOTMULTI/./g;
```

Comment: So it's replacing the strings outside of the group and putting it into the the string literal `DOTMULTI`?

Comment: Okay, now I understand after some examples... Gosh, they literally replaced `...` with `DOTDOTDOTMULTI` as in the string `DOTDOTDOTMULTI`.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters!

Comment: @alvas: Since you work in NLP, you should know it is called *entitization*, and it is a great thing when you want to normalize contents, especially those user generated ones.